How to use Newer Excel functions (like UNIQUE) using Exceljs Library?
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

sheetsData.forEach((sheet) => {
   let ws;
   ws = wb.addWorksheet(sheet.name);
   ws.addRows(sheet.data);
   if (sheet.name === "Inputs - Creative Assets") {
    for (let i = 2; i <= 200; i++) {
      ws.getCell(`C${i}`).value = { formula: `UNIQUE(_xlfn.FILTER('S2 - Creative - Theme Mapping'!$B$2:$B$982, 'S2 - Creative - Theme Mapping'!$B$2:$B$982<>0))` };
    };
  };
};

Here, I'm trying to input the UNIQUE formula in a few cells. The issue is cell adds an '@' symbol infront of the formula and does not recognise it as a formula unless I go into the excel sheet and remove the '@' symbol.
I know you can add _xlfn in front of 'Newer Excel functions' when using xlsx library, but is there something similar that can be done if I want to use exceljs library instead?
